# How can i change error message for email from jQuery-Validation-Engine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I would like to change the error default message for email validation in the [jQuery-Validation-Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine).

I have this input field.

```
<input name="myemail" type="email" data-validation-engine="validate[custom[email],required]"/>
```

Is there a nice way to do this like **data-errormessage-pattern-mismatch="foo"**?

Comment: Your plugin references jQuery 1.4.4, please tell me you are not using that! That's from 2010!

Comment: No, we use not the newest jQuery but i think its ok: jQuery 1.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is :

```
data-errormessage-custom-error="Message"
```